# How to change the shorcut for Paste in Yakuake?

Tags: shortcut-keys, konsole, yakuake

I installed Yakuake 2.9.8 on a Unity desktop. It works quite well, except for two issues with shortcuts. I want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste (because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> is already used as a global shortcut for ClipIt), but there is no shortcut for paste in the "Configure shortcuts..." menu. [This Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1074213) says Yakuake uses Konsole shortcuts for copy/paste, but I see no effect after changing them.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!